# Why isnt this regex picking up my pattern? (works on flash)

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my example http://jsfiddle.net/mwDCV/1/

Using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ i get exactly what i want however in javascript i do not

pattern

```
pass(word)?\=\s*(\<[^>]+\>)*\s*([^<]+)
aka
var myRe = new RegExp('pass(word)?\=\s*(\<[^>]+\>)*\s*([^<]+)', 'gim');
```

text

```
<br />
Run
password=
<br />
test
<br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the RegExp constructor which takes a string, so your backslashes were string escapes.  Use the regexp literal instead, as in the other answer. :)

Comment: are you sure its a string escape. I used `''`

Comment: @acidzombie24, yes!  In many languages (e.g. Bash, Perl, Ruby, etc.) single and double quotes are different, with the backslash only escaping in double quotes but being a literal backslash in the single quotes.  JavaScript is _not_ like that!  Single and double quotes are functionally the same.  Easy mistake!!

Comment: ahh d@#$it I thought '' was kind of like C# @"". Althought i was forced to use perl before and other languages

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
Sorry, I was incorrect about the reason.

The real reason is that in javascript you need to escape your escape slashes like so:

from:
`var myRe = new RegExp('pass(word)?\=\s*(\<[^>]+\>)*\s*([^<]+)', 'gim');`

to:
`var myRe = new RegExp('pass(word)?=\\s*(<[^>]+>)*\\s*([^<]+)', 'gim');`

in order for the `\s` to come out properly.

You can do `console.log(myRe)` and see how the browser parsed your expression (with missing `\`'s).

Seen here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Sxgm/) (old, using `/ /` designation)

But parsing html with regex is frowned upon, you might be better off grabbing the text nodes of wherever this element is and parse that instead (strip the newlines and test for password=.+?)

Comment: huh? i am very confused. I replaced your regex with mine and it works. The difference to get it working was `/.../..` while my original was `new RegExp('...', '..');`. I dont know why the two is different?

Comment: I don't think document.body.innerHTML has anything to do with it.  It's just the backslash within strings vs. backslash within regex literals /.../.  For example `new RegExp('\b')` vs. `/\b/` are different.  See how?

Comment: @Ray yes, sorry, I saw `\<` and thought he was trying to match `\` and `<` since you don't need to escape `<`s.